# FFMPEG error response goes in infinite endless loop

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i https://cdn.dotcompaluat.com/test/running.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -vf \
  scale=w=426:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2 \
 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 96k -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 \
 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 400k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 800k -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod \
 -hls_segment_filename test/240p_%03d.ts  test/240p.m3u8**
```

Above cmd give endless errors' response,  please provide how to manage it.

Comment: Link to full log. Add -report to generate it.

Comment: File appears to be corrupt. Try again with a different input.